# Rails - how to associate nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, associations

I have an organisation model and I have also made a series of nested models under the folder name "stance". One of those models is called overview.

The associations are:

Organisation.rb

```
has_one :overview
```

Stance::Overview

```
belongs_to :organisation
```

My controllers for stance resources are nested under a folder called stance.

My routes are:

```
namespace :stance do
    resources :overviews
    end
```

In my stance view partial, I am trying to render the attributes from the overview table.

I have tried:

```
<p><%= @overview.internal_explanation %></p>
<p><%= @stance.overview.internal_explanation %></p>
<p><%= @stance::overview.internal_explanation %></p>
```

I want to display this partial in my organisation show, but I can't figure out how to access the overview table. Do I need to add a reference to 'stance' in the associations?

I can see that in the console I need to write:

```
o = Stance::Overview.create(internal_explanation: "test")
```

but I can't see how to use that in the code itself.

Comment: What errors do you see from this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the standard naming convention, then you need to give Rails some hints:

```
has_one :overview, class_name: Stance::Overview

belongs_to :organisation, inverse_of: :overview
```

Best place to learn this is to look at the source code comments on `has_many` and `belongs_to`. I'd recommend using an editor that has a "go to source"/"go to declaration" functionality that allows you to CTRL-click a method name and jump into the gem code so you can see the comments. I used this via [Rubymine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) when I was learning Ruby and it was an enormous help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt!

Comment: Is there something special that I need to do to whitelist the strong params in the controller? I changed all the controller actions to include "Stance::" before 'overview', but now I can't find a config that works for the strong params. The error says: param is missing or the value is empty: overview
when I write the params like so:def overview_params
      params.require(:overview).permit(:internal_explanation, :external_explanation )
    end

Comment: Bit hard to work out what you mean without seeing all the controller code. Sounds like this would be best posted as a separate question where you can show it all in detail, plus the error message you get.

Comment: It's ok - I found it - I have to write: params.require(:stance_overview).permit